# Strange scrolling behavior

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a strange problem on a website I developed (*http://misenplacecatering.it/location*).

The problem is that when the browser windows is smaller than a certain size (not sure about the minimum size), using the arrow keys on the keyboard to change the background pictures makes the whole page to move.

I'm using the jquery Supersized plugin for the gallery. Any suggestion?

Comment: ***WARNING*** the site in the link has been hacked and tries to execute malicious code..

Comment: a few hours ago, i visited the site in your question, and i got a warning from Firefox. I viewed the source and found out that there were two `iframes` after the closing of the html tag `</html>`. Those links were loading scripts that tried to run malicious code from my browser and infect my computer..  That is why i disabled the link.. You need to check that your hosting provider as well as your CMS/database is not vulnerable to FTP and database attacks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `width`  from the `#mainmenu` rule, as it extends outside its container and causes the browser to try to scroll when you click the arrows..